# Are independent and dependent clauses reversible?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

In English a phrase such as “Call me when you get home” can be reversed into “When you get home, call me.”

Is this also possible in Chinese?

I tried to answer the question myself, but I could only think of myself using the dependent clause first and never using it second in Chinese class.

Also, all the examples on [AllSet Learning](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22when%22_with_%22de_shihou%22#Examples) have the dependent clause in the beginning, but the site doesn’t specifically condemn the reverse.

Is it grammatically acceptable in Chinese?

Comment: You are better off giving a specific example of Chinese sentence. There isn't a consolidated rule for that.

Comment: "when you come home" in Chinese can be 回家的时候 which usually would come before 请你给我电话，see any E-C dictionary on "when"

Comment: for how to translate search web using e.g.
英文语法 relative clauses, relative pronouns,

Relative clauses are often introduced by a relative pronoun (usually who, which, that, but when, where and whose are also possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not accepted in writing Chinese, however, you can say that in oral Chinese, like

> 给我打电话吧，等你回家之后

The second part of the sentence is served as a complementary clarification and even though, it is not commonly used.

If you write it that way, it is not grammatically acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

In Mandarin, relative (your "dependent") clauses always precede the noun they modify (and there are no really "relative pronouns" in Info-European sense).

The basic word order is subject–verb–object (SVO). Otherwise, Chinese is chiefly a *head-last language*, meaning that *modifiers precede the words they modify – in a noun phrase, for example, the head noun comes last, and all modifiers, including relative clauses, come in front of it*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_grammar#Relative_clauses
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Mandarin